# what's the difference between the two copy constructor invocation in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization

Look at the following codes:

```
class Foo    
{ 
public:  
    Foo(){}  
    explicit Foo(const Foo &){}  
};  
int main()  
{  
    Foo foo1;  
    Foo foo2(foo1);  
    Foo foo3 = foo1; //can not compile    
    return 0;  
}
```

Why `Foo foo3 = foo1;` can not compile, and what's the difference between the two copy constructor invocation?
ps: My compiler tools is GCC4.8.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Foo foo2(foo1);` is [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). `Foo foo3 = foo1;` is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). The difference between them is

> Copy-initialization is less permissive than direct-initialization: explicit constructors are not converting constructors and are not considered for copy-initialization.

The copy constructor of `Foo` is declared as `explicit`, which is not considered in copy initialization.